# Asymptotic Analysis of $f(n)=nf(n-1)+(n-1)f(n-2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, generating-functions

Attempting to solve this via generating functions. I decided to use exponential generating functions. Consequently, by shifting and index multiplying rules, we obtain

$$f(x)=xf(x)+ \int xf(x) dx$$

$$f'(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)+xf(x)$$

Solving this (initial condition $f(0)=1$) yields

$$f(x)= (e^{-x})/(1-x)^2 $$

So I used the following estimation to extract coefficients.

$$[z^n]\frac{f(z)}{(1-z)^\alpha}\sim f(1)\binom{n+\alpha-1}{n}\sim\frac{f(1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}n^{\alpha-1}$$
That's where  my issue is. If we use the first approximation, we get  $(n+1)/e$ and if we use the second one then we get $n/e$.

 To obtain the coefficients of the original sequence, I multiply by $n!$, since I used an EGF.

We obtain finally $(n+1)*n!/e$ or $n(n!)/e$.

From https://oeis.org/A000255, however, I was able to derive $(n+2)*n!/e$. This approximation agrees way more closely to the actual sequence than the above two (The error becomes less than $10^{-2}$ by the 8th term).

The error for the first two estimations though, only increases. Yes, the percent error itself decreases, because the difference between the approximations is multiplying by n or n+1 or n+2, which becomes less significant at greater values.

But I still feel that something's wrong. Are the first two estimations acceptable asymptotic versions produced by the formula, or did I mess up one of the many steps involved.

Cheers

Comment: In this case the relative error tends to zero but the absolute error tends to $\infty$. There's nothing wrong with this, it's still a good asymptotic. It just means some other terms in the expansion also tend to $\infty$, but you have the largest term.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art You mean the absolute error tends to infinity. Thank you, I am glad to know that this is acceptable

Comment: An example of such case wiuld be something like Stirling's approximation for the gamma function, we may think that the error is increasing, but it is indeed an asymptote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for the egf should be
$$(x - 1) F''(x) + (x + 2) F'(x) + F(x) = 0,$$
with the general solution
$$F(x) = \frac {C_1 e^{-x} + C_2 (x - 2) } {(x - 1)^2}.$$
Your solution corresponds to $f(0) = f(1) = 1$. Then the coefficient $[x^n] F(x)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n/e$ (which is also a.e. to $(n + C)/e$ for any $C$).

$C = 2$ gives a better approximation because $2/e$ happens to be the next term in the asymptotic expansion of $[x^n] F(x)$. Since
$$F(x) - \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac {n + 2} e x^n$$
extends to an entire function, we have
$$[x^n] F(x) = \frac n e + \frac 2 e + O(\epsilon^n),
\quad n \to \infty$$
for any $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Why does your DE differ so much from mine though; it is of the second order. Are they roughly equivalent when it comes to the recursion?

Comment: It has to be of second order, to accommodate two initial conditions. Consider that the power series of $\int_0^x \tau F(\tau) d\tau$ starts with an $x^2$ term. If you add $C_0 + C_1 x$ to your integral equation and differentiate twice, you'll get the same second-order ODE.

Comment: I thought that the recurrence itself only requires the specification of one initial condition, since specifying f(0) will allow us to calculate f(1) irrespective of f(-1). Does the number of necessary initial conditions in the recurrence not map directly to the number of necessary initial conditions in the DE?

Comment: If you assume that $f(-1)$ is defined, then indeed you get $f(1) = f(0)$ and there is only one free parameter. But this is not the general solution. One can take two different values for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, then the subsequent values will depend on two independent parameters.

Comment: Understood, and subtle for me. Thanks